# Add suffix in subdirectory, suffix in name of parent directory

Tags: linux

I have few hundreds folders which need to be updated.

```
Main folder m25C, m20C and so on [100 Main folders] 
  Sub folders XYZ_1
              XYZ_2
              XYZ_3
```

I want to rename the subfolders as `XYZ_1_m25C`, `XYZ_2_m25C`, `XYZ_3_m25C`,      `XYZ_1_m20C`, `XYZ_2_m20C`,  `XYZ_3_m20C`,

Can you please guide, I want to read the main directory and add main directory name as suffix to sub directory. I am working in unix environment.

Comment: Have a look at the `rename` command (package `rename` on Debian based distros). Run this to rename the subfolders in a shell script that iterates over the main folders.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
                      
zmv -n '(m<->C)/(*)(#q/)' '$1/${2}_$1'
```

remove the `-n` (dry-run) if happy.